# es6 hash array index function call mixed syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

What kind of ES6 syntax is this?

```
{
  [ActionTypes.Repo](state, { username, res }) {
    /* ... */
  },

  [ActionTypes.Repo2](state, { username, res }) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Taken from : https://github.com/quangbuule/redux-example/blob/master/src/js/reducers/Repo.js

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those are [method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) at work.

**Method definitions** provide a concise way to create properties that contain functions:

```
// before
var obj = {
  foo: function() {}
};

// now
var obj = {
   foo() {}
};
```

That's the same syntax for creating methods in `class` definitions.

**Computed properties** allow you to use the result of any expression as property name in an *object literal*:

```
var foo='somePropertyName';

// before
var obj = {};
obj[foo] = 42;

// now

var obj = {
  [foo]: 42
};
```

And of course this also works with method definitions:

```
var obj = {
  [foo]() {}
};
```

**Destructuring** is like pattern matching and makes it easier to refer to nested properties of an array/object if thats all you need:

```
// before
function foo(obj) {
  var username = obj.username;
  var res = obj.res;
}

// now
function foo({username, res}) {

}
```